# tried to install a python package but encountered "cannot find -lgcc_s" error

Tags: python, gcc

Hi I was trying to install a python package called 'pysptk' under the Ubuntu 16.04, but when I use:

```
pip install pysptk
```

I have encountered the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

However, I already have gcc 4.8.5 installed as 'gcc -v' produces an output. My python version is 3.6.1 and the environment is Anaconda. I have googled the bug but reinstalling gcc and python3-dev does not work.

The code

```
easy_install pysptk
```

will give the following output.

```
Searching for pysptk
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pysptk/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/3d/86/5520242ab99426d8d9b2f18a86ed73f1be848b9fb14e57b2b81b8f17a1bb/pysptk-0.1.8.tar.gz#md5=d34133d2eaccba83f634310602721657
Best match: pysptk 0.1.8
Processing pysptk-0.1.8.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-0xk7me9z/pysptk-0.1.8/setup.cfg
Running pysptk-0.1.8/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-0xk7me9z/pysptk-0.1.8/egg-dist-tmp-wm2zkn7r
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
-- Building version 0.1.8
In file included from /home/luke/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1809:0,
             from /home/luke/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
             from /home/luke/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
             from pysptk/_sptk.c:436:
/home/luke/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: 
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining 
NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I really appreciate your help! If there is any missing information. Please let me know. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know if you should use pip to install packages on Anaconda. Use `conda install` instead to install packages. Likely what's happening is that pip tries to install packages on a different python on your computer, but that Python does not have 'gcc' installed. I run into this issue before when I installed Python from source with the gcc command. Try `pip -V` to see which Python the pip command is callinng.

Another thing I noticed is that you said your Python is Python3.6.1, but you did not use `pip3` command. I suggest you try to do either `conda install pysptk` or `pip3 install pysptk`.